# How to add border on svg image without overlapping the image itself

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, svg

Searched most of similar stackoverflow post with no result as my situation is a bit different.

Trying to add border on an svg image like in these images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfvEyOS.png) but couldn't do it.

I notice that when I increase the border radius, it's overlapping the right top corner of the music icon, so I want the full icon to be visible like in the below image.

[Here](https://svgshare.com/i/Lz2.svg) find the svg image that I'm working on.

Also I found that if you open that svg image using a text editor, there are some information inside; 
I tried to changed the filled color and worked.

Note sure if I have to convert it to PNG or make the svg transparent.

**Tried below code but it's not working / ASP.Net MVC - CSS**

```
<div>
    <img src="~/Content/images/music.svg" class="image-music" />
</div>

.image-music {
    padding: 0.6vh 1vh 0.6vh 1vh;    
    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    background-color: #FF4E50;
    border: 1vh solid #66f51c;
}
```

[image: template picture to follow]

Comment: Can you tell us why you downvoted the question?  As the issue still persist and cannot be solved through other similar post.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a container div and flex box. Also, you'll want separate width and height for the parent container and image inside.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7rh1bteg/52/

```
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #66f51c;
}

.image-music {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

<div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Lz2.svg" class="image-music" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still overlapping with this image [here](https://svgshare.com/i/Lz2.svg)

Comment: You'll need to post a public url to that image if you'd like further help. I cannot access a private drive image.

Comment: I just changed it to a public one

Comment: @Chloe - Thanks. Answer updated. You'll want to use a container div and flex box. Also, you'll want to consider separate width and height for the parent container and image inside.